# Is there any ode solver code such as OPEPACK in fortran 90?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I've been trying to solve some ODEs and looking for fortran code
such as ODEPACK, but I couldn't find fortran 90 version's.
Is there any ode solver code such as OPEPACK in fortran 90?

Comment: What sort of searches have you done that have yielded poor results? We are not here to suggest a tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the Fortran 77 version of ODEPACK from Fortran 90.  Fortran is one of the most backward-compatible programming languages out there.  They didn't want to invalidate all of the good older code.  Using Fortran 90 for your main code does not preclude the use of older libraries such as ODEPACK.

Comment: Fortran is indeed notorious for its backwards-compatibility, and nothing stops JuYongLee from using the Fortran 77 code of ODEPACK in a Fortran 90 program (depending on the compiler, he might need to add a flag indicating legacy code is allowed) . If I understand well though, JuYongLee is looking for an "easier-to-use" ODE solver.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is to implement a Fortran 90/95 subroutine which simplifies the use of legacy code, so that my main program has no direct access to the legacy code at all. There is no real need to re-implement ODEPACK in Fortran 90. There is no need to reinvent the wheel, especially if that "wheel" is ODEPACK, which just works great - the best ODE solver I've ever seen.

Some time ago, I have implemented [DLSODAR_F95](https://sites.google.com/site/pjpapasot/fortran/libraries/dlsodar_f95), which you may want to try. It is actually a Fortran 95 module which simplifies the use of ODEPACK's most powerful (and sophisticated) ODE solver, namely DLSODAR. The module provides a public subroutine, `ODE_DLSODAR`, which you can use instead of the original `DLSODAR` subroutine. `ODE_DLSODAR` is much easier to use, providing the same functionality.

The original Fortran 77 code requires a lot of arguments to be passed, and most of them don't really need to be changed depending on the ODEs to be solved, or the changes needed are trivial. `ODE_DLSODAR` will set up all those arguments and call `DLSODAR` internally to solve the problem. You still have full control over `DLSODAR` by passing optional arguments in `ODE_DLSODAR`, if needed, but normally you just need to call `ODE_DLSODAR` with very few arguments, and the module will take care of the rest.

The package in the link also contains some examples on how to use DLSODAR_F95. If you need other ODEPACK's solvers instead of DLSODAR, I believe you should implement a module similar to DLSODAR_F95 and you should be fine.